# Unable to install ruby on ubuntu 12.04

Tags: ubuntu-12.04, ruby

Hi i want to install ruby on my Ubuntu 12.04. I tried it with following command
`sudo apt-get install curl` but it gives me following error.

```
The hostname -f command returned: $1

Your system needs to have a fully qualified domain name (fqdn) in
order to install the var-qmail packages.

Installation aborted.

dpkg: error processing qmail (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of qmail-run:
 qmail-run depends on qmail (>= 1.06-2.1); however:
  Package qmail is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing qmail-run (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                                                                                      Errors were encountered while processing:
 qmail
 qmail-run
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

How to solve this error. Need Help. I am using ubuntu 12.04

Comment: Could you add the contents of `/etc/hosts` and `/etc/nsswitch.conf`

Comment: thank you andrew for quick replay but there no such hosts or nsswitch.config inside etc

Comment: But what to add in that

Comment: Can you update your question with the output from the following: `cat /etc/hosts`. Also, are these commands being ran as root (so `sudo su -`'d in) or using `sudo`?

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that you do not have a [FQDN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fully_qualified_domain_name) in your `/etc/hosts` file.

Here is an example of what `/etc/hosts` should contain:

```
root@precise64:/home/vagrant# cat /etc/hosts
127.0.1.1       precise64.example.com precise64

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
```

Once you have corrected the `/etc/hosts` file, you can check your FQDN with `hostname -f`

```
root@precise64:/home/vagrant# hostname -f
precise64.example.com
```

You should be able to `sudo apt-get install qmail` after the changes.

Comment: OK andrew I will try this and let you whether its working or not. Thank you for help.

Comment: H andrew according to your solution i update my hosts file but still it is giving same problem.

Comment: When you run `hostname -f`, what is the output?

Comment: hostname -f shows me nilkash.com.example which is same as set into hostname field and hosts file